# Splitting line by other lines using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, splitting

I have two shapefiles. The first: a line. The second: several lines overlapping the first line.

For some reason, I can't split the first line manually so now I want to split it where it's being overlapped by the other lines. Hopefully, this is possible without having to click on each overlapping feature in editor mode (I can't click on anything at all in editor mode).

Comment: do you have editing rights to the data?

Comment: Of course! I have literally an empty map with just one line and the lines I want to use to cut the first line. I'd be happy if I could split the the line in some way at all but nothing seems to work. Now, please give me some good advice before I go insane.

Comment: Are both shapefiles in the edit session / same projection etc.? Can you edit the first line by itself alone in a fresh ArcMap session?

Comment: Use interest on both line feature classes, output - point. Use split lines at points afterwards.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What are the precise steps that you have performed between starting ArcMap with a blank map and seeing your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Feature to Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-line.htm) tool, input both line features, the result will be split lines:

> Creates a feature class containing lines generated by converting
>   polygon boundaries to lines, or splitting line, polygon, or both
>   features at their intersections.